# jQuery: toggle text on hover over image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, how can I get text to toggle when the user hovers over an image?

I have code that changes the text when the user hovers:

```
# HTML
<table id="support-people">
<tr>
<td><img data-bio="Bio 1" src="person1.jpg" alt="Person 1"/></td>
<td><img data-bio="Bio 2" src="person2.jpg" alt="Person 2"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">
<p id="support-person-description">Default text</p>
</td></tr></table>

# JS
$('#support-people img').hover(function(){
    $('#support-person-description').text(this.getAttribute("data-bio"));
});
```

But when the user moves away, the text stays the same - is there a neat way I can get it to toggle back to the original, default text?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the two functions of hover (first for mouse over, second for mouse out) then in the first save the oldtext as data on the element. Then read this value and set it in the second function:

```
$('#support-people img').hover(function(){
    var desc = $('#support-person-description');
    desc.data('oldtext', desc.text()).text(this.getAttribute("data-bio"));
}, function() {
    var desc = $('#support-person-description');
    desc.text(desc.data('oldtext'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
$('#support-people img').hover(function(){
    var $elem = $('#support-person-description');
    $elem.data('oldText', $elem.text()).text(this.getAttribute("data-bio")); // Add text on mouse hover
},function(){
    var $elem = $('#support-person-description');
    $elem.text($elem.data('oldText')); // Return to default
});
```

Comment: Would that set the `p` tag to blank since the default text is being replaced on hover? I would think you'd need to somehow store the default text first.

Comment: Yep, you're right ! Not seen that he want the previous text back... Edited

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript to the following.

```
$('#support-people img').hover(function(){
    $('#support-person-description').text(this.getAttribute("data-bio"));
}, function(){
    $('#support-person-description').text('Default text');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write onMouseOver and onMouseOut functions in the same call
http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

the `.hover()` method requires TWO parameters. On for what happens when hovering and one for when not hovering. Your code only has the instruction to display the element. You are missing the instruction to remove it again.

Comment: It doesn't require two, if you only specify one it will run that function on mouseover and mouseout.

Comment: agreed, but to do what you needed required the use of two, as in the answer you chose.